# ng-repeat not updating when ng-click function clicked

Tags: angularjs

I have a GET function to list names, and another function that is triggered by an ng-click, that needs to update the ng-repeat where the lists of names are being at displayed by the get function. But it is not working. This is my code:

**Container where the GET function displays:**

```
    <div class="container names-container" ng-controller='namesCtrl'>
<div ng-repeat='name in names.pData'>
    <div class="name-box chiuv">
        <p class="name-name">{{ name.name }} {{ name.last_name }}</p>
        <p class="name-date">{{ name.date}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Search modal with the ng-click**

```
<div class="output">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="output" id="nameH" ng-model="inputName" placeholder="Search by name">
</div>
<div class="hebk"></div>
<button class="search-btn" ng-click="searchName()">SEARCH</button>
```

**Functions**

```
    var fetch = angular.module('myapp', []);

fetch.controller('namesCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.getNames = function() {
        $http({
            method: 'get',
            url: '<?= base_url(); ?>/display/getNames'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            // Assign response to users object
            $scope.names = response.data;
        });
    }
    $scope.getNames();

    $scope.searchName = function() {
        $scope.names = '';
        $http({
            method: 'post',
            data: {
                name: $scope.inputName
            },
            url: '<?= base_url(); ?>/display/searchNames'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            // Assign response to users object
            $scope.names = [];
            $scope.names = response.data;

        });


    }



}]);
```

Comment: `ng-click` has `getName` while controller has `getNames` function with extra s. Can you correct that first or I am missing something here.

Comment: The correct one is ng-click="searchName()"

Comment: Please check the developer console of your browser if any errors occur when you click the button. It would be nice if you could provide any error logs

Comment: no errors are being logged, just blank

Comment: When the page loads, if you put in a break point at the getNames, $scope.names = response.data; Does this return the expected data? Instead of calling your endpoint for every search name, why don't you filter through the names already given? Can you verify your endpoint is sending back data when posting to it? There are many possible points of failure here. Maybe the data is being saved back correctly, but the properties or .name, last_name, and .date are not properly formatted.